# Factory Girl - how to include one association's ID while defining another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

A `Task` belongs to an `Employee`, who belongs to a `User` (polymorphic).

`Task` also has `user_id` (the same user).

Now how to create this situation using FactoryGirl?

```
factory :employee do
  after(:create) { |employee|
    user = FactoryGirl.build :user
    user.roleable_type = "Employee"
    user.roleable_id = employee.id
    user.save!
  }
end

factory :task do
  employee
  user employee.user.id
end
```

Running a test that creates a task, I get:

```
/Users/ss/Documents/app/spec/factories.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `user' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007fbd67cd2c70> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Try `user employee.user` instead of `user employee.user.id`?

Comment: @Surya No difference, I'm afraid.